# Can we run AirSim on cloud server such as Google Cloud or Azure?

Tags: airsim

I am trying to run AirSim simulation on cloud servers since my computer cannot afford run it.  It causes overheat.

I received the errors below

1. Azure
   "insufficient driver or hardware"

```
"LogInit: Error: Linux_PlatformCreateOpenGLContextCore - Could not create OpenGL 4.3 context, SDL error: 'Could not create GL context: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)'"
```

2. google cloud

```
"LogInit: Warning: Could not initialize SDL: XRandR support is required but not available

LogInit: Error: FLinuxApplication::CreateLinuxApplication() : InitSDL() failed, cannot create application instance."
```